# Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c Plugin development

Tags: oracle, plugins

I am very new in developing a plugin for Oracle Enterprise manager. I have setup my work environment(installed Adobe Flex builder,Extensibility Development Kit(Edk) and all). I have also succesfully deployed a sample plugin to OEM grid control. Now I have a few queries which can be solved by someone who already done plugins in OEM(Hope SE contains some). I have posted in oracle's forum,but getting no response. Here are my queries:

```
1) Is it possible to add the Sample plugin created also to be listed when selecting the targets from Enterprise>Monitoring>Logs? If yes, how can I do that.
2) Also, in that case can I add a custom UI instead of showing logs in table.
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who came across the same problem and get here through google,
please go to https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2481432&tstart=15 for details.